# Intellisense for Ionic 2 is not working in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, ionic2

I just created a project using `ionic start Project blank --v2`. I then opened it in Visual Studio 2015 using the "New Project from Existing Code". I then chose "Apache Cordova" as the project type.

Then i go and create an `html` file in the `www/app` directory. Inside the blank html file, i start typing `<ion` and no intellisense comes up.

How can i get ionic intellisense working inside visual studio 2015?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as any typing information, we're still working on that. See [this issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2/issues/84). So we'll be able to provide the proper intellisense once we get that resolved.

As for the html part of it, I'm not sure thats anything to do with us. This is still super early alpha, so I'm not sure if VS has had time to add the proper code-hints.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is ionic2 uses .js for typescripts as specified in tsconfig.json  `"allowNonTsExtensions": true`

Visual Studio looks at app.js and sees that as plain javascript and does not understand the typescript constructor (and other parts of the class) and complains.

@mharrington Why don't the ionic team just use .ts and then transpile/compile into .js? Lot more files but not confusing.

There's quite a lot of people looking for IDE support for debugging (from IDE) and intellisense in angularJS that's available on top of TFS and rest of the goodness VS already provides. I'm sure if Ionic can provide licensed support for Visual Studio the way Telerik and DevExpress provide, we'd be push the Upper Management to buy the licenses.

Yes it is still at an alpha stage.

Comment: Are you sure it is TypeScript and not ECMAScript 6?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use Ionic Pack Extension for Visual Studio 2015, developed by Mads Kristensen. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d6279fba-bcff-4857-906d-29faa8a99448?SRC=VSIDE